# Expectation of $\frac{\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\rm{T}}}{\| \mathbf{x} \|^{2}}$ for $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation, normed-spaces, trace, random-matrices

Let $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$. I would like to compute the following expectation:

$$\mathbb{E} \bigg[ \frac{\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}}}{\| \mathbf{x} \|^{2}} \bigg] = \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \frac{\mathbf{X}}{\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{X})} \bigg]$$

where I have defined $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}}$. It is know that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{T}}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}] = \boldsymbol{\mu} \boldsymbol{\mu}^{\mathrm{T}} + \boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, but this does not help much since numerator and denominator cannot be considered separately.

I would expect that many people have encountered this problem before, but its solution seems far from straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

$||x||^2=x^tx=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2$. Note that the $i^{th}$ diagonal element of $xx^t$ is b$x_i^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that $\| \mathbf{x} \|^{2} = \mathbf{x}^{\mathrm{x}} \mathbf{x}$ and that the absolute values appear on the diagonal, but I don't understand how this is supposed to help. Can you please be a little more precise in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for the case where $\Sigma=I$. In that case, the expectation is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{XX^T}{||X||^2}\right] =
\frac{1}{n}{}_{1}F_1\left(1; \frac{n}{2}+1; \frac{-||\mu||^2}{2}\right)I + \frac{1}{n+2} {}_{1}F_1\left(1; \frac{n}{2}+2; \frac{-||\mu||^2}{2}\right)\mu\mu^T
\end{equation}

where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, I)$, $n$ is the number of dimensions of $X$, and ${}_1F_1(a;b;c)$ is the hypergeometric confluent function.

I posted the derivation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605559/expected-value-of-the-inverse-squared-norm-of-non-centered-random-vector/606660#606660), in a separate question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community I have edited the answer to be clearer.